# nodemailer nodejs: sendmail exited with 127

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, npm

I would like to send an email from my server (kimsufi), to confirm registration.

So, i use **nodemailer** https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

I have this error:

```
Error occured
Sendmail exited with 127
```

What's mean ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this example
https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/blob/master/examples/example_sendmail.js

Then replace this code

> var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("Sendmail",
>   "/usr/sbin/sendmail");

With

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: true, // use SSL
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "foo@rcorp.co.in",
        pass: "fooP@ssword"
    } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your sendmail path is correct. To check, open a terminal and issue:

```
which sendmail
```

Comment: If sendmail exited with an error code, why would we think the path was wrong?

Comment: The error is issued by the nodemailer sendmail engine, not sendmail itself. See https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/blob/master/lib/engines/sendmail.js

Exit code 127 is "command not found"